# Continuous joint distribution function and the cdf

Tags: calculus, probability

$f$ is a jointly continuous distribution function
$f(x,y)=Cx^2 y^2$   where       $0<y<1$,$y^3<x<y^{1/3}$

C is a constant.

Find $\mathbb P\{0<x<1/4\}$  and  $\mathbb P\{0<x<1/4│y=1/8\}$?

This is not a homework but a practice question.

---

To find $C$, we assume $\int_0^1\int_{y^3}^{y^{1/3}}f(x,y)dxdy=1$

$C=18$?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? Have you found the constant $C$ ?

Comment: By assuming the distribution function integrated to 1 we could find C. I will show my work?

Comment: You just asked another question about evaluating $f_X$ and the conditional density. You could have waited for an answer to those before posting this question.